How to make Galaxy Note 4 look like A11?
Is there any quick way to change the style/theme on this old Note 4 to look more like Galaxy A11 as below?


Have you tried to install a different launcher app? Anyway skinning a ten year old phone wont make it faster if better, just the opposite by wasting RAM for the skin.
